# How to serve a file for any matching GET request with warp?

Tags: reactjs, rust, warp

I am using React in the frontend development and doing client-side routing with `react-router`. While intergating with my `warp` backend, I have come across some obstacles.

After building the React app with `npm run build`, I move the build folder to my Rust project. According to `create-react-app` [documentation](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing). I need to serve `build` folder and serve the `index.html` file for any matching `GET` request. I could not achieve this in `warp` like the `express` example in the documentation.

Here is the build folder example.

```
build
├── asset-manifest.json
├── favicon.ico
├── index.html
├── manifest.json
├── robots.txt
└── static
    ├── css
    │   ├── main.089e2544.css
    │   └── main.089e2544.css.map
    └── js
        ├── main.ba6a006a.js
        ├── main.ba6a006a.js.LICENSE.txt
        └── main.ba6a006a.js.map

3 directories, 10 files
```

Here is `index.html` line where includes the script.

```html
<script defer="defer" src="/static/js/main.ba6a006a.js"></script>
```

Using `warp::fs::dir("build")` was enough to see main page since it includes `index.html` file in the background. But if I to manually type URL for example `127.0.0.1:8080/login` and press enter it does not process the request.

Comment: can you put a reproducer to github ?

Answer (score 0):

The way to implement a "fallback" is to simply use [`.or()`](https://docs.rs/warp/latest/warp/trait.Filter.html#method.or) which will attempt to use the next filter if the one before didn't match. So if the required behavior is to serve from the `"build"` directory or else serve `"build/index.html"`, that can be done like this:

```
use warp::Filter;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let routes = warp::filters::fs::dir("build")
             .or(warp::filters::fs::file("build/index.html"));

    warp::serve(routes)
        .run(([127, 0, 0, 1], 8080))
        .await;
}
```